# Bootstrap select position show ticks

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, dropdown

Is it possible the tick shows on right side?
I'm trying to edit my CSS Code bu nothing changes! Only the options in my dropdown-menu, like these:

> Css

```
.dropdown-menu {
 position: relative;
 top: 100%;
 right: 0;
 z-index: 1000;
 display: none;
 float: right;
 min-width: 160px;
 padding: 5px 0;
 margin: 2px 0 0;
 list-style: none;
 font-size: 14px;
 background-color: #fff;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
 border-radius: 3px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
 box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0,0,0,.175);
 background-clip: padding-box;
}

.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
 margin-left:10px;
}
```

> HTML

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-sm-8 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <label>Sistemas Operacionais</label>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSistemaOperacional" runat="server" onchange="carregarAbas()" CssClass="form-control" multiple data-live-search="true">
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*" Text="*"
                    EnableClientScript="true" ClientValidationFunction="validaSistemaOperacional" ValidationGroup="1"
                    ValidateEmptyText="true" Display="Dynamic" CssClass="text-error" ForeColor="">Campo obrigatório</asp:CustomValidator>
    </div>
</div>
```

The ticks shows on the left of texts. I'd like to shows the ticks on the right side of the texts! Anyone?

Comment: please provide the pure html code

Answer (score 0):

```css
.dropdown-menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  min-width: 160px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  margin: 2px 0 0;
  list-style: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
  border-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, .175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
  -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li {
  position: relative;
}
.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  display: block;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  clear: both;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li a span.text {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.bootstrap-select.btn-group.show-tick .dropdown-menu li.selected a span.check-mark {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  right: 15px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

Comment: hi @Ankrea My code is exaclty like yours and it works!!! But, the ticks still on left...I realy need the ticks on the right! I tried so much codes, but still on left...

Comment: Hi Leonardo. Maybe try with ':after'
{
    content: "\e013";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-size: 9px;
    float: right;
}

Comment: how can I try with "after"? Could your edit your code above!? thanks a lot!! @Ankrea

Comment: Compare  your code with this example https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#checkmark-on-selected-option .